# How to access ViewHolder in RecyclerView with regards to layout calculation

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have created a `RecyclerView` and have set the proper adapter and `LinearLayoutManager`. I'm able to access my `ViewHolder`s just fine outside of the `onCreate` method. During my research of the problem, it appears that in order to access a `ViewHolder`, the `LinearLayoutManager` must finish calculating the positions of the views before you're able to use either the `findViewHolderForAdapterPosition` or `findViewHolderForLayoutPosition` methods.

I would like to modify only one of the views inside of the many viewholders I add to the `RecyclerView`.

I'm currently attempting (and failing) at accessing the views/viewholders in any of the `Activity` life cycle methods (`onCreate`, `onStart`, `onResume`). I see that `LinearLayoutManager` has a `onLayoutCompleted` method, but am unsure how to make use of that for my situation.

Is there anyway to gain access to either the views or the viewholders inside the `RecyclerView` during one of the `Activity` life cycles or somehow figure out when `onLayoutCompleted` is called by the `LinearLayoutManager`? Is there another way around this?

Theoretically I could add all the viewholders into a list inside the adapter and access it that way, but that doesn't seem quite so clean.

Answer (score 0):

Try to hold a list of models inside of the adapter. If you need to change the view, just change the model and call `RecyclerView.Adapter.notifyItemChanged(int p)` or `notifyDataSetChanged()`.